# Install "scientific python" environment: OS X 10.7 + Numpy + Scipy + Matplotlib

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, scipy

What could I have done instead in order to get these items working together? Should I just move everything to windows 7 (I'd prefer not, but if it's the only reliable way.)

Okay, so here's what's happened: I wanted to install numpy/scipy onto my mac, which runs 10.7. Unfortunately numpy ver1.6 only supports up python 2.6. I go and install python 2.6, But python 2.6 doesn't work; app-icon bounces and automatically quits. (This strange in retrospect, because I heard python 2.7 and numpy ships with mac; but when I tried using sample code from the numpy website it failed.)

Now in a real bind, so I eventually found this: http://stronginference.com/scipy-superpack/
Which somehow installs numpy 2.0, Scipy (0.11), Matplotlib (1.2), iPython (0.12), Pandas (0.5.1) as well as PyMC (2.2 alpha).

It seemed like it worked, Numpy did work with some example code they provided on python 2.7. But as I was working on practice problems, I found that matplotlib is not working at all anymore. The python launcher (I think.... it's python launcher app-icon, but just says "python" for the name) bounces in the app tray and eventually freezes. I was worried it could be because I had matplotlib 1.1 installed before, so I followed instructions to clean uninstall matplotlib followed by installation with scipy-superpack.

Still fails the same way as before. Now I've done a clean install of matplotlib 1.1 in hopes that it works. And when I "import pylab" it throws up a ton of error messages.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Doesn't help you directly, but if you find yourself back on windows, [Python(x,y)](http://code.google.com/p/pythonxy/) does this nicely.

Comment: i already deleted the matplotlib 1.1, so i can't see the error msgs anymore. but it said stuff like "transformer" "linear" "fourier" i think. Thanks for the python(x,y) mention; it looks pretty sweet i have to say.

Comment: The link to stronginference.com seems to be broken.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is super old but it's high up on Google, so I just wanted to chime in with Anaconda--

https://www.continuum.io/downloads

Just a graphical installer that you run to install it like anything else, no messing with `.bashrc` or anything. Has numpy, scipy, I think it might have sklearn, basically everything you'd want with Python--plus it doesn't require root access/Windows UAC, which can be critical in certain corporate/government environments that are locked down tight. Works for Mac and Windows, never tried it with Linux.

Answer (score 13):

If you are ready to follow a longer term approach, I would advise that you go through the [MacPorts](http://www.macports.org/) **package manager**: they have all this software packaged, and it just works.  I followed this approach successfully with Mac OS X Lion.

You basically first install the MacPorts package manager, and then [install programs](http://guide.macports.org/#using.port) like explained on their site: `sudo port install python27 py27-numpy py27-scipy py27-matplotlib py27-ipython`.

One advantage of the MacPorts approach is that you **do not touch Mac OS X's original software**: their programs are stored in `/opt/local/` (along with some programs in `/Applications/MacPorts/`, like Gimp or Python's Idle).  The install procedure should put `/opt/local/` in front of your path, so that you automatically use MacPort's programs instead of those installed by default on the Mac.

Another advantage is that MacPorts **automatically downloads any additional necessary programs** (dependencies) for you.

[Their packages](http://www.macports.org/ports.php) are quite **up-to-date**, and there are **many** of them (12k+, at the time of this writing).  So, with the MacPorts route, you'll have access to many additional programs.

Side note: I have a long experience with the another package manager for Mac OS X: Fink.  I find MacPorts simpler, more robust, and more up-to-date.  So, I heartily recommended it.

**PS**: I believe that you also have to create a new `python` MacPorts command with `sudo port select python python27`, and do the same for IPython: `sudo port select ipython ipython27`.  These commands in effect define which version of Python and IPython will be called when you use the `python` and `ipython` commands in a shell.

**PPS by JD Long**: I tried following these instructions on May 16, 2012 and, possibly because of versions, or possibly because of idiosyncrasies on my Mac, I had to also run `sudo port install py27-tornado py27-zmq` in order to get a fully functioning ipython/notebook stack working.

Comment: Sorry, how is it supposed to work after it's installed? I just used your installation command-line.
Is there a particular thing I need to put at the top of the script file like "import macports"? I'm going to try youtubing for the answer as well. But one thing I was really wondering was whether or not there are performance hits for using macports? I'll be running machine learning algorithms (uses matrices). Thanks for your help so far!!!!

Comment: You should not have anything special to do in oder to use the MacPorts program, as long as they appear first in your shell path (see my PS, though).  The result of `which python` in the Terminal should be `/opt/local/bin/python` (that's MacPort's Python).

Comment: @MattSweeney: Yeah, I'd be curious to know how homebrew and MacPorts compare.

Comment: @MattSweeney: as far as I understand, homebrew does not contain as many versions of the programs.  This may be a problem: if one wants to test code with Python 2.4, 2.5, 2.6, 2.7, 3.1 and 3.2 before releasing it, MacPorts can provide all the relevant Python versions; this is very convenient.

Comment: @Shinjitsu: There is *no performance hit* for using MacPorts. You might even obtain faster programs: they come in multiple variants (including some that might be optimized for your usage; see MacPorts' help), and they are compiled specifically for your machine.

Comment: @EOL Oh Finally....... the sword has been pulled from the stone! I have graphing capability now! This would have been a huge pinball + maze if not for your guidance. Thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 11):

Another option would be [EPD](http://enthought.com/products/epd.php) or [EPD Free](http://enthought.com/products/epd_free.php).  Either will install NumPy, SciPy, matplotlib, IPython, Traits, and Chaco on Window, OSX, or Linux.  EPD is the kitchen-sink-included version with 90+ libraries for science and analysis, and is available on a subscription basis (free for academics).  EPD Free is free for all- commercial use, redistribution, etc.

Comment: this looks pretty promising as well. I sort of like how they say it's optimized for performance and compatibility. I was looking to do some serious work thru this. Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

[Installing Python, virtualenv, NumPy, SciPy, matplotlib and IPython on Lion or Mountain Lion](http://www.thisisthegreenroom.com/2011/installing-python-numpy-scipy-matplotlib-and-ipython-on-lion/) guides you through the steps.

(Note, current version of the guide, as of 2013, is now here:  [Installing scientific Python on Mac OS X](http://www.lowindata.com/2013/installing-scientific-python-on-mac-os-x/) )

1. A clean install of Mac OS 10.7 Lion
2. Installing Homebrew
3. Installing Python (and pip)
4. Installing virtualenv
5. Installing NumPy, SciPy and matplotlib
6. Installing IPython and the qtconsole

with 3 pages of clear, narrative text.

(He also has some funny comments, good links: [I can chartjunk and so can you](http://www.thisisthegreenroom.com/2012/i-can-chartjunk-and-so-can-you/) "... a tutorial that will actually destroy information in 25 steps".)

Answer (score 3):

You can also try to package your numpy/scipy/matplotlib/... installation using virtualenv.
A step by step recipe to do it using homebrew is described [here](http://www.thisisthegreenroom.com/2011/installing-python-numpy-scipy-matplotlib-and-ipython-on-lion/).
It worked fine for me.
Hope it helps.

Answer (score 2):

Here are some resources i have relied on to troubleshoot getting my scientific python rig up on Snow Leopard and Lion.

[HyperJeff Blog](http://blog.hyperjeff.net/?p=160)

i first used this reference for Snow Leopard, then again for Lion. It is an excellent and very thorough step-by-step guide to installing 64-bit NumPy, SciPY, and Matplotlib on Mac OS X 10.6 (though it seemed to be equally helpful for 10.7). This "survival guide" has a couple of things going for it:

- it is a ***step-by-step*** guide that makes very few assumptions, so for
  instance, the first step is configuring your .bash_profile with the
  appropriate environmental variables for deployment target, package
  config paths, cflags.
- it actually ***supplies the code***--the individual shell commands to retrieve/download, configure, build, and install all three Packages and their dependencies; in addition, this blog Post supplies the diffs of all config files which the author recommends to edit prior to installation
- it is ***vetted by the community***--there are perhaps 100 or so comments to the original Post,
  nearly all of which the author responded to and in some cases,
  revised the text of his original guide; in addition, the comments
  cover quite a few edge cases.

[Washington University Astrology Department](http://www.astro.washington.edu/users/rowen/BuildingMatplotlibForMac.html)

This began with 10.3 (Panther) but it is actually up to date; they just haven't bothered to revise this document in cases where the revision is a trivial change, e.g., from 10.3 to 10.7.

This resource is useful because it discussed in detail what always seems to be the problem for me--NumPy and SciPy are ok, but Matplotlib fails, and it fails because of libpng, libjpeg, et al.

---

Some (empirically) likely causes of a failed install of NumPy/SciPy/Matplotlib (all, unfortunately based on personal experience):

***[libpng](http://www.libpng.org/pub/png/libpng.html), [freetype](http://freetype.sourceforge.net/index2.html), [zlib](http://zlib.net/)***: all Matplotlib dependencies. One possible source of problems, but not the only source is caused by Matplotlib versions above 1.0 which do not compile (by "default") against libpng version 1.5, yet that that's the version a developer is likely to have on their Mac, because it's the version included with the X11 shipped with the 10.7 versions of XCode (version 4.0 - 4.2). This issue aside, it's a good idea to use [XQuartz](http://xquartz.macosforge.org/trac/wiki) rather than the Xll supplied with XCode. Likewise, in the past the Apple-supplied X11 included a broken version of freetype (v. 2.3.12, in particular)

***Matplotlib's default config***:the most straightforward way to opt out of these defaults is to edit the make.osx and setup.cfg.template files, both included in the Matplotlib source top-level directory. The Posts in the HyperJeff blog (above) and [Supine Sublime](http://voidptr.wordpress.com/2011/03/29/compiling-matplotlib-1-0-1-on-64-bit-mac-os-x-leopard-for-python-2-7/) blog are very helpful on this set of issues.

***Apple-Supplied Fast Fourier Transform Library***: various issues here; i believe one of the most persistent was the lack of Fortran bindings in the FFT library version supplied with the Mac Developer Tools. In any event, it's not difficult to just get the latest version of the gold standard for FFT libraries, [FFTW](http://www.fftw.org/) and install it from source.

Comment: Thank you as well, there was a good likelihood that this could have solved the issue as well. I just choose macports because I'm not sure how well l could implement those fixes, and I plan on using this for some real world work. But if I ever run into another matplotlib issue, I will return here. Thank you!